# dotnet path not found when run program with sudo

Tags: .net, sdk, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

when I run a compiled program with sudo, ex: `sudo ./program` it says:

> You must install .NET to run this application.
>
> App: /home/pi/program
> Architecture: arm
> App host version: 6.0.10
> .NET location: Not found
>
> Learn about runtime installation:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
>
> Download the .NET runtime:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=arm&rid=raspbian.11-arm&apphost_version=6.0.10

Yet it's installed in both accounts, `root` and `pi`, I know it has to do with sudo, but I don't know how to fix it. Afaik sudo creates a clean environment but no matter if I disable the `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers` or even adding the paths there, it just keeps showing the above message.

I've installed the script version of dotnet 6.0.10 in a raspberry pi 3b+:

`uname -a` output:

> Linux raspberrypi 5.15.74-v7+ #1595 SMP Wed Oct 26 11:03:05 BST 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux

And I have exported both paths to env in `root` and `pi`:

`.bashrc` content:

> export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/.dotnet
> export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet

I have rebooted several times after each modification, env paths are updated accordingly yet it keeps failing

The only way it works is logging in as root with `sudo su` or `sudo -i` but it's a headache doing this every time I want to run my programs with root access

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the simplest solution is always the best.

`sudo` has a param -E which preserves the environment, so it recognizes the dotnet path.

A simple solution is to run `sudo -E ./program` or create an alias to include -E and preserve the environment for every use.

[sudo params showing the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdUd5.png)